# find primes function

Tags: python, primes

I have a function:

```
def containsNoDivisor(n, ps):
    '''n is an integer and ps is a list of integers. Returns True if
    and only if there is no integer in ps that divides n.    '''
    for p in ps:
        if n % p == 0:
            return False
    print True
```

Then I need to create another function, that computes a list of primes < n, from the function above. So far I have:

```
def findPrimes(n):
    primes = [2]
    for i in range(3,n):
        if containsNoDivisor(i, primes):
            primes.append(i)
    return primes
```

But it is returning True's instead of the primes?

Comment: Um, why is `containsNoDivisor` printing `true` instead of returning it?

Comment: Small update(s) would increase the performance by huge factor. Take a look at this gist I posted to another question a few weeks ago https://gist.github.com/1347515

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're printing `True` instead of returning it in your `containsNoDivisor` function. It should look like this:

```
def containsNoDivisor(n, ps):
    '''n is an integer and ps is a list of integers. Returns True if
    and only if there is no integer in ps that divides n.    '''
    for p in ps:
        if n % p == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

The `print` statement simply outputs the value to the console - if you're trying each function in the interactive shell, it's an easy mistake to make.  `return` will actually take the value and pass it back to whatever called it, allowing data to be used outside of the function that created or processed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
def containsNoDivisor(n, ps):
    '''n is an integer and ps is a list of integers. Returns True if
    and only if there is no integer in ps that divides n.    '''
    for p in ps:
        if n % p == 0:
            return False
    print True
    ^^^^^
 should be return
```

Answer (score 0):

You are testing every number from 3 to n.  You don't need to test even numbers since all evens > 2 are composite.  Try stepping 2 rather than 1: 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, ...